# How to use multiple dataproviders in a single codeception(a php based test automation framework) test?

Tags: codeception

I use codeception which is a php based test automation framework.

I need to use multiple dataproviders in a single test class.

I know how to use a single dataprovider per test; example of my code below:

```
use Codeception\Example;

    /**
     * @dataProvider charProvider
     */
    public function sampleTest(Example $data) {
        //iterating through the array of data points contained in the data provider: 
        $data_point_char = iterator_to_array($data->getIterator());
        print_r($data_point_char['data']);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function charProvider() {
        return[
            ['data' => 'a'],
            ['data' => 'b']
        ];
    }
```

Now my requirement is to use another data provider: numProvider() within the same test:

```
protected function numProvider() {
        return[
            ['data' => 1],
            ['data' => 2]
        ];
    }
```

I am not sure, how the iterator_to_array() will reference this second data provider and iterate through it as in the code I used, this iterator_to_array() method is using a pretty generic parameter:

`iterator_to_array($data->getIterator())`

Not quite getting how individual data provider can be referenced in this manner?

And if individual dataproviders can be referenced independently within a same test, then following that multiple dataproviders can be used within the same test.

Kindly suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Codeception 5 allows to specify multiple data providers for test method. Test method is executed repeatedly with each data item from each data provider, in your example `sampleTest` will be executed 4 times.

It is completely unnecessary to use `iterator_to_array($data->getIterator());` for converting instance of `Example` class to array. `Example` implements `ArrayAccess` interface, so data from data provider can be accessed as array element - `$example['data']`.

```
/**
 * @dataProvider charProvider
 * @dataProvider numProvider
 */
public function sampleTest(Example $example) {
  var_dump($example['data']);
}
```